# counting rows returned from a query

Tags: php, oracle

when i use oci_fetch_array and count i get 22(which i think it means its getting two rows) which is wrong it should be 11(11 is the number of columns) and 
when i use oci_fetch_row i get 1 which is right. 
can anyone tell me why this is happening?

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM USERS WHERE USERNAME= :uname AND PWORD = :pword";
$stmt = oci_parse($c, $sql);

$uname=$_POST['uname'];
$pword=$_POST['pword'];

oci_bind_by_name($stmt, ":uname",$uname);
oci_bind_by_name($stmt, ":pword",$pword);

oci_execute($stmt);


$res = oci_fetch_array($stmt);
$res2 = oci_fetch_row($stmt);
$num = count($res);
$num2 = count($res2);
echo $num . "<br/>";
echo $num2 . "<br/>";
```

Answer (score 3):

According to the [docs](http://dk.php.net/oci_fetch_array), oci_fetch_array works just like [mysql_fetch_array](http://dk.php.net/mysql_fetch_array), so you have to run through the array.

That means, you only save your first row in your oci_fetch_array, instead you should do like this

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM USERS WHERE USERNAME= :uname AND PWORD = :pword";
$stmt = oci_parse($c, $sql);

$uname=$_POST['uname'];
$pword=$_POST['pword'];

oci_bind_by_name($stmt, ":uname",$uname);
oci_bind_by_name($stmt, ":pword",$pword);

oci_execute($stmt);

$data = array();

while($res = oci_fetch_array($stmt))
{
  $data[] = $res;
}

$num = count($data);
echo $num . "<br/>";
```

Comment: Thanks, just found that myself, it works and is much simpler to use, Still dont understand why i get one right answer and a wrong answer doing the otherway but anyway thanks again.

Comment: This should return the same as your `oci_num_rows`, but is an horribly inefficient way to do it.

Comment: @clonebaby59 - I have the impression that you haven't understood the two answers you've got so far, which are both correct. Your code does not *get the right answer* because it's not even getting a row count; it's getting a column count.

Answer (score 1):

The oci_* library is not too dissimilar to mysql_* in php.

Fetch array will return something similar to this

```
Array(0 => "some_key" => "some_value")
```

Where as fetch assoc will return

```
Array("some_key" => "some_value")
```

I can't remember entirely but I'm sure this is the root of your problem.